# Different JSON serialization for the same class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Common enough problem: a class that I want to serialize in two different ways. In one case I want to include the output of `getItems()` method and in another case I don't want to see this in the output.

Chose to use Jackson Views as it gives me the maximum flexibility. Created:

```
public class Views {
    public static class WithOrderItems {
    }
}
```

Then in the class to be serialized:

```
@JsonView(Views.WithOrderItems.class)
public Iterable<OrderItem> getItems() {
    //Code...
}
```

In the method doing the serialization:

```
// Expectation: this *should not* include "items" in JSON output
mapper.writeValueAsString(retObj)
```

returns the same as:

```
// Expectation: this should include "items" in JSON output
mapper.writerWithView(Views.WithOrderItems.class).writeValueAsString(retObj)
```

In both cases the entire object is being serialized (it's as if the View is being ignored). Why is this happening?

Most of the documentation, tutorials etc. I can find online are for older versions of Jackson. Is there some setting that I am missing out on? As far as I understand, methods annotated with a view **should not** be included in a default `mapper`.

My `mapper` configuration is:

```
public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule())
            .registerModule(MoneySerializer.getAsModule());

static {
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT);
}
```

(The `getAsModule()` is temporary code. `MoneySerializer` is for Joda Money objects and isn't being invoked in this case.)

Want to avoid mixins as that means static configuration of what is output and what isn't.

Using:

- Jackson: 2.6.1
- Java 7
- GAE SDK 1.9.30
- Objectify 5.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand, methods annotated with a view should not be
>   included in a default mapper.

I do not think it is true. If you do not provide any view, mapper should serialize everything.

> NOTE: even if you only want to use "default" view -- that is, just exclude things that are only to be included in specific "full" view -- you DO need to enable View processing by specifying a view. If you do not have explicit "basic" view setting, just use Object.class.

Taken from [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)

Answer (score 2):

### To clarify and expand on answer by @ghokun ...

So to **exclude** `"items"` (or more generally, fields/methods which have a special view assigned to them), use:

```
mapper.writerWithView(Object.class)
```

and to **include** `"items"`  (or more generally, fields/methods which have a `Views.WithOrderItems` view assigned to them), use:

```
mapper.writerWithView(Views.WithOrderItems.class)
```

Using just plain `mapper` (i.e., without an `ObjectWriter` obtained from `mapper.writerWithView(...)`) will include everything.